# @error Laravel directive for several fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is there a simple way to use the **@error** Laravel Blade directive conditionally for several fields?
For example, if *field1* **or** *field2* contains validation errors, I was wondering if there is some way to use the directive like that (note that the following example is not valid):

```
@error('field1' || 'field2')
   ...
@enderror
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#validation-errors) say that "*we may pass the name of a specific error bag as the second parameter to the @error directive to retrieve validation error messages on pages containing multiple forms*", but  nothing about this feature.

Finally, if you consider it is not worthy, what would be the Laravel way of implementing such condition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, also in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#determining-if-messages-exist-for-a-field):

```
@if ($errors->has('field1') || $errors->has('field2'))
   ...
@endif
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Not much point repeating it here then, if its in the manual

Comment: check the duplicate, `hasAny` is for this purpose

Comment: Thanks! Pretty much what I was looking for :)